# For extractor: google.com:EmailBodyExtractor just (.*) regex is working

Tags: regex, gmail-contextual-gadgets

Does anyone knows if there is a bug in google API, because when I am using extractor google.com:EmailBodyExtractor, the only regex used for param value which displays results is this ".*". 
When I try this regex ".*test", even there is word "test" in the body of my email it doesn't return any results. Using this same regex ".*test" with extractor: google.com:SubjectExtractor it returns results, by finding test in the subject of my email.

Comment: dot won't match a newline character.

Comment: Well, to think of it, it should work unless the regex is anchored by default, and I do not think it is. If it is anchored, try `[\s\S]*test`. In many cases, you do not need `.*` unless you want to match some characters other than a newline before or after a searchword. Maybe all you need is just to search for `test`. What results do you expect?